# Need some CCFL transformer help

Tags: transformer

I was wondering about [these transformers](http://uk.farnell.com/coiltronics/ctx210609-r/transformer-ccfl-3-6w-5vdc/dp/2075582). It says it requires a DC input (I think) however don't transformers need an AC input, and if so does that mean I would need to make an oscillator circuit to pulse the DC? Or can I just input AC?

Answer (score 1):

5VDC is just a misprint in the catalogue. Lower down it says:

- Primary Voltages: 1 x 13V
- Secondary Voltages: 1 x 1.34kV

So you should give it 12-13V AC, preferably as a sine wave, and will get just over a kilovolt on the far side. Take care to keep the two secondary outputs well away from one another and well insulated.

Comment: I don't think anyone bothers to drive CCFL light transformers with a sine wave. Square-wave or modified square-wave is much easier, and the CCFL lights don't care about waveform anyways.

Comment: Does it have a noticable effect on EMC or efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about driving it, this diagram in a Linear technology article shows a connection method - it uses a Coiltronics CTX110092-1 which has the same coil configuration as the type you listed: -
[image]